# Stubbing Google Maps/Places iOS SDK calls for unit testing

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, ohhttpstubs

I'm trying to stub my Google Places calls using a local `json` file.  Using Charles proxy, I find that the Google Maps SDK uses the url `https://www.googleapis.com`.  So, I try to stub like:

```
stub(isHost("https://www.googleapis.com")) { request in
    OHHTTPStubsResponse(fileAtPath: "google_maps.json", statusCode: 200, headers: ["Content-Type":"application/json"])
}
```

But it's not intercepting the google maps SDK calls.  Any ideas?  Could this be the Google Maps SDK using something other than Cocoa's URL Loading System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given here:  (I was using the incorrect host name, should use simply "www.googleapis.com")

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/issues/219